# Install .tar.bz2 program on Debian

Tags: debian

All the guides/StackExchange posts say use the 'make' command, or ./configure, or autogen.sh, after extracting the tar.bz2 with the help of `tar -xvjf`.

However, this package (Sublime Text 32 bit linux) has none of those in the directory, only a pre-compiled program, which works, but is not visible to the system. How can I add this program to the Debian Linux directory so that it is registered as an application? Ex. If I open a file, and click on 'Open With', Sublime Text should show up among all the other applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After downloading and extracting you will have a directory called **sublime_text_3**. Move the directory to /opt

```
sudo mv sublime_text_3 /opt/sublime_text
```

You can create a symlink for opening it from the terminal

```
sudo ln -s /opt/sublime_text_3/sublime_text /usr/local/bin/sublime_text
```

Link the .desktop file to your applications directory

```
sudo ln -s /opt/sublime_text_3/sublime_text.desktop /usr/share/applications/sublime_text.desktop
```

Do not change the paths, because the sublime_text.desktop file already has paths written to search for the binary.